# How to open new terminal by C code?

Tags: command-line, c

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and Qtcreator to complile a code.
I am able to run a terminal by code `system("/home/salman/find_location/start_yarp.sh");` 
But on the next line i have `system("/home/salman/find_location/start_icub.sh");` I want to open the the second `.sh` file in new terminal. How can i open a new terminal? i have already tried `system("gnome-terminal");` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Try `"x-terminal-emulator -e \"your command\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
system("x-terminal-emulator -e \"/home/salman/find_location/start_yarp.sh\"")
```